# Fork exec and pipe with bash script

Tags: c

I would like to put the output from a bash script (`sc.sh`), which is in the same directory as this program and which contains line below, to the input of a C program (`cprog`); executing `cprog` works but I do not know why the bash script is not starting:

```
timeout 5 cat /dev/urandom
```

and this is the main program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid1, pid2;
    char * input[] = {"/bin/bash", "sc.sh", argv[1], NULL}; 
    char * output[] = {"./cprog", argv[1], NULL};

    pipe(fd);

    pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1 == 0) {
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        execv(input[0], input);   
        return 1;
    }

    pid2 = fork();
    if (pid2 == 0) {
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[1]);
        execv(output[0], output);
        return 1;
    }

    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);
    waitpid(pid1, NULL, WNOHANG);
    waitpid(pid2, NULL, WNOHANG);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Szymon, you should consider using indentation. :)

Comment: You should check the return values of your function calls.

Comment: Also posting includes section would save a little bit of somebody's else time when running the code.

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors.  When you duplicate a pipe file descriptor to standard input or standard output, you should almost always close _both_ of the pipe's file descriptors.  You may get away with it, but..

Comment: One obvious step is to report any errors — that would help identify if the system thinks there's a problem.  At minimum, before the `return 1;` lines, use `perror(input[0])` and `perror(output[0])` respectively.  Your `waitpid()` calls are not very useful: you don't wait for the children to die, and you don't check their exit status, and you don't report what it finds.  Frankly, you would do as well leaving them out as including them — especially if the intent is run the processes in the background.  You've also not explained why you pass `argv[1]` to `sc.sh` — what you show doesn't use it.

Comment: _You need bash -c._ Not necessarily

Comment: @EOF: If you run `bash -c sc.sh` then the argument passing is different.  At the command line, running `bash sc.sh` will work; `bash sc.sh arg1 arg2` provides 2 arguments.  Using `bash -c 'echo 0=$0 - 1=$1 - 2=$2' arg0 arg1 arg2` outputs `0=arg0 1=arg1 2=arg2`.

Comment: Szymon, I used this `#!/bin/bash\n cat - > output` in place of `cprog` and your program works just fine. As @JonathanLeffler suggested, add `perror` to see what's wrong

Comment: http://ideone.com/CJBEAb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your program to report errors and actually wait for the children to die, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc > 2)
        fprintf(stderr, "Excess arguments ignored\n");
    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid1, pid2;
    char * input[] = {"/bin/bash", "sc.sh", argv[1], NULL}; 
    char * output[] = {"./cprog", argv[1], NULL};

    pipe(fd);

    pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1 == 0) {
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execv(input[0], input);   
        perror(input[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    pid2 = fork();
    if (pid2 == 0) {
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execv(output[0], output);
        perror(output[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);
    int status1;
    int corpse1 = waitpid(pid1, &status1, 0);
    printf("PID %d: %d (0x%.4X)\n", pid1, corpse1, status1);
    int status2;
    int corpse2 = waitpid(pid2, &status2, 0);
    printf("PID %d: %d (0x%.4X)\n", pid2, corpse2, status2);
    return 0;
}
```

I used a simple C program as `cprog`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    unsigned sum = 0;
    unsigned cnt = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        sum += c, cnt++;
    printf("sum of bytes: %u\n", sum);
    printf("num of bytes: %u\n", cnt);
    return 0;
}
```

Testing on the command line yielded:

```
$ bash sc.sh | cprog
sum of bytes: 325895667
num of bytes: 69926912
$
```

Running the main program (it was `p19` created from `p19.c`) yielded:

```
$ ./p19
sum of bytes: 372818733
num of bytes: 70303744
PID 28575: 28575 (0x7C00)
PID 28576: 28576 (0x0000)
$
```

The exit status shows that the `timeout` exited with status 124, which is what GNU documents as the exit status when the command times out.

So, in my reproduction of your environment, the code you provided works OK.  That suggests that your environment is not set up as you think.  Maybe the `sc.sh` script isn't there.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to fix the problem by closing those file descriptors and also rewriting the cprog. Your code was really helpful.